# Why my program is failing with null pointer exception

Tags: java

I am working on a test assignment where i have to take name and phone number from the user ans save them to the arraylist.
I created three classes

- Contacts: to store contact details.
- MobilePhone: to store the contacts objects.
- Mobilemain : begins program execution.

Following is the content of the classes:

**Contacts.java**

```
    package mobilephone;

    public class Contacts {
    private int number;
    private String name;

    public Contacts(String name,int number ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**MobilePhone.java**

```
package mobilephone;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MobilePhone {
    private ArrayList<Contacts> phonebook = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

    public void addPhone(Contacts contact) {
        phonebook.add(contact);
    }

    public void showContacts(){
        for(int i=0 ;i< phonebook.size();i++){
        System.out.println(phonebook.get(i).getName()+" => "+phonebook.get(i).getNumber());
        }
    }


}
```

**Mobilemain.java**

```
package mobilephone;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mobilemain {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Contacts contacts;
    static MobilePhone mobilephone;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        addContact();       
        mobilephone.showContacts();
    }

    static void addContact(){
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name= scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter phone number");
        int number= scanner.nextInt();
        mobilephone.addPhone(new Contacts(name,number));

    }


}
```

But on executing the  main class i am getting below error.

```
Enter name: fgsdg
Enter phone number
234234
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mobilephone.Mobilemain.addContact(Mobilemain.java:19)
    at mobilephone.Mobilemain.main(Mobilemain.java:10)
```

I verified that the object i am passing at line 19 in Mobilemain.java is not null

Comment: `mobilephone` is null

Comment: `mobilephone` not initialised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MobilePhone is null, you have to initialize the variable first:

```
static MobilePhone mobilephone = new MobilePhone();
```

Only then you can use the addPhone

Comment: syntax error `()`

Comment: @suraj I have updated it before everybody downvote him ;)

Comment: Wow sorry i had a sintax error Shashwat, thank you suraj